# Change NavigationBar color (background color)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I keep reading to change the default color on a navigationbar i just need to update the first method in the appdelegate to this

```
self.window.rootViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

but it doesn't seem to work, so I tried setting it in the viewDidLoad method of the firstview also:

```
self.parentViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

This didn't work either. How can I change this?

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `self.parentViewController`, but `self`:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

When iphone 5 come we have to set both device type. So use this

```
if([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] ) {
    //iOS 5 new UINavigationBar custom background
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbg_ForiPhone5_Imagename.png"] forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
} else {
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbg_ForOtherIphone_Imagename.png"]] atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: I prefer using the UIImage over the tint color. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In IOS7 you can try this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

You can follow these steps:

I created a new `UINavigationController` for example `UIDemoNavController` resulting in:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];  
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

This is the full demo class:

```
#import "UIDemoNavController.h"

@interface UIDemoNavController()

@end

@implementation UIDemoNavController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {}
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`
`UIViewController` class has a property `navigationController`, which returns the navigation controller its embedded in no matter how deep, otherwise it returns `nil`.